# Using Terraform to create a service account with IAM roles

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a basic Service Account with the `roles/logging.logWriter` IAM role with Terraform. Below is how I have configured this:

```
resource "google_service_account" "log_user" {
  account_id   = "log-user"
  display_name = "Logging User"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "log_policy" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/logging.logWriter"

    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.log_user.email}"
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_policy" "log_user_policy" {
  service_account_id = "${google_service_account.log_user.name}"
  policy_data        = "${data.google_iam_policy.log_policy.policy_data}"
}
```

When running `terraform apply` I am receiving the following error message:

```
* module.iam.google_service_account_iam_policy.log_user_policy: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_service_account_iam_policy.log_user_policy: Error setting IAM policy for service account 'projects/arcadia-apps-237918/serviceAccounts/log-user@arcadia-apps-237918.iam.gserviceaccount.com': googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/logging.logWriter is not supported for this resource., badRequest
```

From the digging I've done I can't seem to find a clear cut explanation on how to create a Service Account and then attach a role to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I resolved this by doing the following:

```
resource "google_service_account" "log_user" {
  account_id   = "log-user"
  display_name = "Logging User"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log_user" {
  project = "arcadia-apps-237918"
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.log_user.email}"
  ]
}
```

The user running `terraform` needs to have the IAM Admin role assigned to them before you can do this.