# how can we add project number from variable in terraform gcp resource iam binding

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Below is my terraform resource. how can we add project number from variable in terraform gcp resource iam binding because if i will run same terraform for other account, i have to change it manually.

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project = var.projectid
  role    = "roles/container.admin"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:service-1016545346555@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?

Comment: @adp,   i want to use like "serviceAccount:service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com"   so when i try same thing in other account, it picks from variable.tf or gcp global variables. after all, i don't want to hard code it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The project number is found in the [google_project data-source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/project).

So when this one is added:

```
data "google_project" "project" {}
```

it should be accessible using:

```
data.google_project.project.number
```

Comment: i got my final answer by the combination of your answer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737583/using-terraform-to-create-a-service-account-with-iam-roles